# What is the proper place to release a NSURLConnection in the following example?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management

I have the following statement in my viewWillAppear controller:

```
connectionInprogress = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

What is the proper place to release it? That is can I just do it in viewDidUnload or does it make more sense to do it in viewDidDissapear?

I guess the fundamental question here is that does viewDidUnload get called every time a viewDidDissapear gets called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `viewDidUnload` is paired with `viewDidLoad` and may never get called, which is why you should also release your instance variables in `dealloc`. `viewDidUnload` is called if the view controller is sent a memory warning.

You should release the`NSURLConnection` in the callback functions: `connectionDidFinishLoading:` and `connection:didFailWithError:`. Only one will be called.

Check out the [Xcode documentation for URL Loading System Programming Guide : Using NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation, it'll be the fastest way

[viewDidUnload](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidUnload)
[viewDidDisappear](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidDisappear%3a)